# ZF2 - ViewModel children (ViewModel->addChild()) are not rendered

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have following Action in one of my controllers:

```
public function validateMessageAction() {
        $sth = new ViewModel($this->params('params')); 
        $adServerOutput = $this->forward()->dispatch('Adserver/Controller/Index', array('action' => 'index'));
        $sth->addChild($adServerOutput, 'adServerOutput');

        return $sth;
}
```

Next I have a following template:

```
adServerOutput: <?php echo $this->adServerOutput; ?><br><br>
Validate message link clicked<br>
```

Of course the Adserver/Controller/Index and corresponding template exists as well, can be called and once called - shows correct output (from its template).

Unfortunatelly what I get after going to validateMessage action is only the "Validate message link clicked" text - nothing that is setup in Adserver/Controller/Index->indexAction().

Any idea why that works this way ?

*Additional information to that might be that actually the `validateMessageAction()` is also triggered from different controller via `$this->forward()->dispatch(...)` - maybe that might be the case ?*

**EDIT**: I have checked that as well - and even if the `forward()` call is only done once - still the problem persists...

**I will really greatly appreciate any hints - sitting on this for 2 days already and have no clue even what to check further :)**

**EDIT:** ADDITIONAL TESTS and information
I have done some additional tests and found here are some additional info:

- adServer/Controller/indexAction has a layout.phtml template that specified layout (for test purposes shows string "AdServer Layout")
- validateMessageAction has a layout.phtml tenplate that specified layout as well (for test purposes shows string "validateMessage Layout)

Now when I only try to call

```
$a = $this->forward()->dispatch(...)
```

even if $a is not assigned or anyhow used (only this association is performed) - the page immediatelly starts using Adserver layout (but still contents are not shown) - ignoring the layout that was specified for validateMessageAction() (of course when I remove that assotiation - the layout for validateMessageAction() is back immediatelly).

As I understood in the [documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html) forward should not make any action, but rather only result with string containing rendered module.

There can however be one additional information in here - is that I use [EdpModuleLayouts](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts) - maybe that might be somehow source of the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `echo` in front of `$this->adServerOutput;` in your child template? ie `<?php echo $this->adServerOutput; ?>`

Comment: @Crisp add an answer

Comment: Yes, I was... sorry must have removed by accident while cleaning up the code a bit to show the exact, separated problem...

Comment: You say: *"nothing that is setup in `Adserver/Controller/Index->indexAction()`"* What are you exactly doing in `indexAction`?

Comment: indexAction of Adserver simply echoes other string - nothing fancy (yet :))

Comment: To be more precise - indexAction in Adserver returns empty array() and the text I would expect to show up in $this->adServerOutput is specified in the phtml template attached to that indexAction. This text shows correctly if I call the indexAction from  browser.

Comment: SOLVED -  Problem was coused by EdpModuleLayouts - removing layout for Adserver (which actually should not have a layout) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

Problem was caused by EdpModuleLayouts - removing layout for Adserver (which actually should not have a layout) solved the problem.